# Check existing attribute with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I`m pretty sure Im doing it right but for some reason its not working.

```
 if($('[parent='+val+']').length > 0){
        $('[parent='+val+']').each(function(){
        }
}
```

anyone know what am I doing wrong here? I cant find it..

Comment: Do you really have HTML with some nodes with an attribute name of `parent`? Depending on `val`, you might have to enclose it in double quotes. Post your HTML.

Comment: @CertainPerformance tnx man, I guess I had to wrap it up with "